# How can I optimize my SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server

I have one table which contains some members and their card. There are 3 unique type of cards i.e. ADIB, ADCB & NBAD. One person may have more than one card & also one person may have more than one type of card i.e 2 ADIB cards.

Below is my query, how can I optimise it?

```
create table #cobrand(grp_number nvarchar(12), partner varchar(5))

insert
into #cobrand
select distinct c_grp_number grp_number, 'NBAD' partner from partnership_cards c where partner_name = 'NBAD'
and not exists (select grp_number from #cobrand t where c.c_grp_number = t.grp_number)

insert into #cobrand
select distinct c_grp_number grp_number, 'ADIB' partner from partnership_cards c where partner_name = 'ADIB'
and not exists (select grp_number from #cobrand t where c.c_grp_number = t.grp_number)

insert into #cobrand
select distinct c_grp_number grp_number, 'ADCB' partner from partnership_cards c where partner_name = 'ADCB'
and not exists (select grp_number from #cobrand t where c.c_grp_number = t.grp_number)
```

Comment: We are here to help and answer questions, not do your work. We are not a free programming service

Comment: @Olearn Dear Olearn, we are here to learn new things, new techniques. so i want something new approach for this. its learning only not my work.

Comment: We don't have access to your screen or your databases. What is wrong with the query now and why do you think it needs optimising?

Comment: @Mazhar it is working fine but i need the approach through which it can be done in one query only, not like my way..these are multiple queries.

Comment: @NishantKhanna You should've said that in the question

Comment: Please time this query when running it, explain what tables are in use and how many rows each of them has, and obtain a query explain plan for your readers. Are you looking for a general speed increase, and if so, by how much? Don't add this information to comments: **edit your question** please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe..?

```
INSERT INTO #cobrand
SELECT DISTINCT
       c_grp_number AS grp_number,
       partner_name AS partner
FROM partnership_cards c
WHERE partner_name IN ('NBAD','ADCB','ADIB')
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM partnership_cards e
                 WHERE e.c_grp_number = c.c_grp_number
                   AND ((c.partner_name IN ('ADCB','ADIB') AND e.partner_name = 'NBAD')
                    OR  (c.partner_name = 'ADIB' AND e.partner_name IN ('NBAD','ADCB')));
```

Impossible to test without sample data though.

Answer (score 0):

As @Larnu says, unable to test without test data

```
INSERT INTO #cobrand
SELECT DISTINCT
    c_grp_number
    ,c.partner_name
FROM
    partnership_cards c
WHERE
    c.partner_name IN ( 'NBAD', 'ADCB', 'ADIB' )
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM
        #cobrand t
    WHERE
        c.c_grp_number  = t.grp_number
    AND c.partner_name  = t.[partner]
) ;
```

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS` in this query won't achieve anything; the table `#cobrand` is empty prior to this `INSERT`.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention that the `#cobrand` table is empty

Comment: The fact that they `CREATE` the table is a very strong indication. Tables don't contain any data on creation.

Comment: I assumed that was for our purposes (provide partial DDL) to help the OP:-)

Comment: I did think so too, but then I ***hoped*** that the OP wasn't effectively asking us to change a `=` to an `IN`. It looks more like a FIFO operation, and that values of `'ABCD` can only be inserted if one for `'NBAD'` doesn't exist, and `'ADIB'` can only be inserted if a value for neither `'NBAD'` or `'ADCB'` exists. That's the logic that would be applied in their sample query.

Comment: That's the issue with this question isn't it. :-) We are making too many assumptions. The OP needs to be more clear.

Comment: I agree, however, I'm not hopeful for any further elaboration from them though. They've been silent for over 30 minutes now.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c_grp_number, partner_name from 
        (select c_grp_number, partner_name, 
            row_number() over (partition by c_grp_number order by partner_name desc)
        as flag
        from sameer_db..etihad_partnership_cards_temp
        where card_status = 'Active' and partner_name in ('NBAD', 'ADIB', 'ADCB'))t
        where flag = 1
```

Comment: This answer includes columns (`card_status`, `flag` ) not mentioned in the original question

Comment: @Larnu Can you please tell me how you did change the format of the query i posted.

Comment: I highlighted the code and pressed the **`{}`** button.